# SQL Server - single Inline Query - (decimal remainder of x/y (rounded to 6 characters) ) / z

Tags: sql-server-2008, rounding

Can I ask for help on a SQL Statement please, I have to do the calculation inline and cannot declare variables for it

Calculation:

```
-91000000 / 2700000 = -33.7037037037
```

I need the remainder (7037037037 - but only up to 6 characters ) to be multiplied by 15000

703703 / 15000 = Final Answer of 49.913533

I thought I could do this:

```
select cast(ParseName(abs(cast(-91000000 as decimal)/ 2700000 ) %1,1) as numeric(8,8)) / 15000
```

Comment: "multiplied by 15000" but you show division `703703 / 15000`. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT -91000000 AS x, 2700000 AS y
)
SELECT ABS(ROUND((CAST(x AS decimal) / CAST(y AS decimal)) - (x/y), 6)) * 1000000 / 15000 FROM CTE
```